# Resize 3d cube base on screen size

Tags: swift, scenekit

let's say I have a 3d cube of this size.

Height: 1002.0
Width:  564.0

The cube size is based on image size, here's how I'm creating the cube:

```
 let image = UIImage(named: "img")

 artRoomScene.setup(height: image!.size.height / 600, width: image!.size.width / 600, position: SCNVector3(0, 0.4, -1.5), rotation: SCNVector4(0,30,0,-56))
```

Obviously, the cube will be way too big for any iPhone screen if I don't divide it by 600. 
But instead of dividing by 600. How can I resize the cube Proportionally to the iPhone screen size?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the % you want, let's say you want a 20% of the screen width:

```
let desiredWidth = view.frame.width * 0.2
```

and setup the `artRoomScene`

```
image!.size.width / desiredWidth
```

Comment: bigger than what? current screen size? you have to decide the percentage you need

Comment: Yes bigger than the Screen! Let's say the new image size is 4000 x 6000. How do I adjust the percentage automatically?

Comment: For example: If the image size is 4000 x 6000. The equation would be:  let desiredWidth = contentView.frame.width * 4.5.

Comment: yes, if you want that. but why you need so big image?

Comment: It's an app that allows users to pick an image and add it to a cube. Do you have any idea how I can change the percentage automatically?